# error al ingresar datos de c++ a mysql

Tags: c++, base-de-datos

metodo donde se ingresan los datos
pero por alguna razon no me los ingresa a la base de datos me devuelve que los datos
no se ingresaron de manera correcta no estoy seguro si es por la manera en la que estoy llamando al metodo o en la consulta si me puedieran ayudar se los agradeceria de ante mano gracias .

```cpp
//aqui es donde mando a llamar al metodo
int main()
{
    string nombre, apellido, genero,correo;
    int telefono=0, nit=0;
    conexion cn = conexion();
    if (cn.getconexion()) {
        cout <<"conexion exitosa"<<endl;    
        tablas tb = tablas(nombre,apellido,genero,correo,telefono,nit);
        tb.pedir();
        tb.datos();
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "no se conecto" << endl;
    }
    cn.cerrarcone();
//aqui esta el metodo
int  tablas::datos() {
    conexion cn = conexion();
    if (cn.getconexion()) {
        int q_estado;
        string n = to_string(nit);
        string tel = to_string(telefono);
        string insert = "Insert into clientes(nombres,apellidos,nit,genero,telefon,correo,fecha)values('"+nombre+"','"+apellido+"','"+n+"','"+genero+"','"+tel+"','"+correo+"','current_timestamp()')";
        const char* i = insert.c_str();
        q_estado = mysql_query(cn.getconexion(),i);
        if (!q_estado) {
            cout << "Datos insertados" << endl;
            return q_estado;
        }
        else {
            cout << "No se logro insertar datos" << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No se logro hacer la conexion" << endl;
    }
    
    cn.cerrarcone();
}
```

Comment: te recomiendo mostrar por consola el insert e intentar validar que tenga todos los datos y la sintaxis correcta, después ejecútalo manualmente desde tu administrador de base de datos.

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda si era error en la sintaxis específicamente donde esta el current times_tamp no debe de llevar comillas simples

Comment: suele pasarle hasta a los expertos...

Answer (score 0):

En la creación de la sentencia query debes tener en cuenta cuándo estás insertando un dato creado por tu programa y cuándo estás invocando una función *built-in* del motor de base de datos.

Si especificas el valor del campo fecha como `'current_timestamp()'`, estás asignando un valor literal, no estás indicando que utilice la función `current_timestamp()`. No debe llevar los delimitadores.

Un detalle adicional, no estás realizando validación del contenido de los valores que insertas en la base de datos y generas el query con valores que parece que son entrados directamente por el usuario. Eso es un problema de seguridad, te pueden hacer inyección de código con un esfuerzo mínimo.